# Common Lisp Hash-Dot #. Reader Macro

Tags: common-lisp, reader-macro

Recently, I have come across the so-called hash-dot Common Lisp reader macro and am wondering how it works and what it does. Using search engines was not of much help, so any examples, explanations and especially uses-cases are most welcome.

Comment: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhf.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the spec this is called sharpsign dot. It does read-time evaluation. You can search the Common Lisp hyper spec for that. I don’t have it to hand but I believe in Emacs with slime one can look up the documentation for reader macros. Do `C-c C-d C-h` to see if there is a command for that.

`#.foo` reads as whatever `(eval foo)` returns. Thus:

```
CL-USER> '((+ 1 2) #.(+ 1 2))
((+ 1 2) 3)
CL-USER> (read)
#.(* 3 4)
12
```